# Need help with Change of variables.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have an expression something like this 
$$\int_{\Omega_t} |\nabla_yu|^2 dy $$
and i want to change the variables via $y : \Omega \to \Omega_t $

$y= x+ tv(x)+ \frac{t^2}{2} w(x)$

Can someone help me to find the expression $$\int_{\Omega} ...... dx$$

I have tried but i have failed . 
Thanks in advance.